# accessing values in a nested arrray with a variable value

Tags: arrays, nested

i'm having some difficulty accessing a value from a stdClass object that is nested in an array.  the issue is that the nested array value is not consistant, I'm wondering if there is a way of accessing it with some sort of a wildcard or parseing of the path? here is the output of the array....

```
Array
(
    [order_id] => 251
    [uid] => 1
    [order_status] => balance_pending
    [order_total] => 50
    [product_count] => 1
    [primary_email] => 
    [delivery_first_name] => 
    [delivery_last_name] => 
    [delivery_phone] => 
    [delivery_company] => 
    [delivery_street1] => 
    [delivery_street2] => 
    [delivery_city] => 
    [delivery_zone] => 0
    [delivery_postal_code] => 
    [delivery_country] => 840
    [billing_first_name] => 
    [billing_last_name] => 
    [billing_phone] => 
    [billing_company] => my company
    [billing_street1] => po box 678
    [billing_street2] => 
    [billing_city] => garb
    [billing_zone] => 1
    [billing_postal_code] => 95542
    [billing_country] => 840
    [payment_method] => check
    [data] => Array
        (
            [coupons] => Array
                (
                )

            [complete_sale] => logged_in
        )

    [created] => 1392066915
    [modified] => 1392066930
    [host] => 127.0.0.1
    [currency] => USD
    [products] => Array
        (
            [259] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [order_product_id] => 259
                    [order_id] => 251
                    [nid] => 71
                    [title] => attributesw
                    [model] => uuuu
                    [qty] => 1
                    [cost] => 0.00000
                    [price] => 50.00000
                    [weight] => 0
                    [weight_units] => lb
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [percentage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [6] => downpayment
                                        )

                                )

                            [shippable] => 0
                            [type] => new_prod
                            [module] => uc_product
                        )

                    [rdf_mapping] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [order] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [order_id] => 251
                            [uid] => 1
                            [order_status] => balance_pending
                            [order_total] => 50
                            [product_count] => 1
                            [primary_email] => chrysalis72@hotmail.com
                            [delivery_first_name] => 
                            [delivery_last_name] => 
                            [delivery_phone] => 
                            [delivery_company] => 
                            [delivery_street1] => 
                            [delivery_street2] => 
                            [delivery_city] => 
                            [delivery_zone] => 0
                            [delivery_postal_code] => 
                            [delivery_country] => 840
                            [billing_first_name] => 
                            [billing_last_name] =>
                            [billing_phone] => 
                            [billing_company] => 
                            [billing_street1] => 
                            [billing_street2] => 
                            [billing_city] => garb
                            [billing_zone] => 1
                            [billing_postal_code] => 95542
                            [billing_country] => 840
                            [payment_method] => check
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [coupons] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [complete_sale] => logged_in
                                )

                            [created] => 1392066915
                            [modified] => 1392066930
                            [host] => 127.0.0.1
                            [currency] => USD
                            [products] => Array
 *RECURSION*
                            [quote] => Array
                                (
                                    [accessorials] => 
                                )

                            [line_items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [line_item_id] => subtotal
                                            [type] => subtotal
                                            [title] => Subtotal
                                            [amount] => 50
                                            [weight] => 0
                                            [data] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [order_uid] => 1
                )

        )

    [quote] => Array
        (
            [accessorials] => 
        )

    [line_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [line_item_id] => subtotal
                    [type] => subtotal
                    [title] => Subtotal
                    [amount] => 50
                    [weight] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [rdf_mapping] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

The value I am trying to get at is [nid] which is found here....

```
[products] => Array
        (
            [259] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [order_product_id] => 259
                    [order_id] => 251
                    **[nid] => 71**
                    [title] => attributesw
                    [model] => uuuu
                    [qty] => 1
                    [cost] => 0.00000
                    [price] => 50.00000
                    [weight] => 0
                    [weight_units] => lb
```

The problem is that the value of the nested array (in this case [259]) is always changing, i'm wondering if there is a way to get at the nested value of [nid] without knowing the value of the array it is in. such as a wildcard. Sorry if my terminology is not proper, this is not my speciality, hope it makes sense to you.  thanks much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out....after reading my own question, I realized I could parse the array for the key and then use that key to get the value.